# What are the best practices/tools for a team of 7 developers working in Visual Studio Proffessional?

Tags: visual-studio, alm

What are you guys using, what has worked for you? I'm talking about, version control, testing, automated build, code coverage, basically all things ALM. The cheaper the tools, the better. We are not looking for VSTS.
For profit, commercial application and custom software development in C#. Programming is primary skill.

Comment: ALM? 
VTSTS?

Also: What domain are you working in and language are you using? These will effect some of those choices.

Comment: What is the skillset of your team and the primary focus of your company?  Do you guys develop software and make money selling it or do you spend most of your time developing internal tools?  Do you have a team of professional software developers or domain experts who have picked up programming as a secondary skillset?

Comment: For profit, commercial application and custom software development in C#. Programming is primary skill.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Version Control: Subversion. You can get the Visual SVN plugin for Visual Studio which is relatively cheap and gives you integration in the IDE.

Testing: NUnit w/ Rhino Mocks for mocking. Does everything you need.

Automation: MSBuild. It comes out of the box with Visual Studio and can be made to do everything you need. Look at the [MSBuild Community Tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/) for some extra good plugins.

Code Coverage: Both NCover and PartCover work fine. PartCover is free. The old NCover 1.5 is free assuming you can find it, the newer one is too expensive. So try PartCover. Look at the attachments on the site for the MSBuild Task.

Continuous Integration: CruiseControl.net is free and fine.

Answer (score 6):

- [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) -- source control
- [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) -- Subversion server
- [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) -- Subversion client
- [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/) -- Subversion plugin for Visual Studio
- [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) -- Continuous Integration server
- [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) -- ReSharper VS plugin and NUnit test runner
- [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/index.php) -- unit test framework

Total cost is ~$200/developer assuming that you don't exceed the project limit on TeamCity. I don't have a suggestion for a code coverage tool.

Comment: I second ReSharper - I had never used it before my current job, but it's by far one of the most productive and worthwhile tools I've ever had the pleasure of using.

Comment: I third ReSharper - you don't realize how integral it becomes to your daily development until you have to use someone's machine without it installed

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using [git](http://git-scm.com/) as version control. It's free, and used as the version control for Linux and many other big projects. It has a bigger learning curve, but it's worth the effort in the long term.

And before thinking of specific tools, focus on people. There are many cheap or even [free tools available](http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/07/23-.NET-Open-Source-Projects) (I suppose you're working with .NET in my link). Try letting them look for the tools they like best, and you'll have developers much more motivated.

Answer (score 0):

Personaly we use VS 2010 Premium with TFS 2010 and it works very well for us.

This answer is based on the assumption that your not looking to VSTS because you believe it is prohibitvley expensive.  Whilst this used to be the case in the VS 2008 era is is no longer a tool for the rich only, and its intallation and maintenance is much simpler too boot.

Assuming your using VS as your IDE and further assuming you get this via an MSDN subscription then I would strongly recommend you consider TFS 2010 as an ALM tool (its free with the Visual Studio Pro with MSDN subscription).

VS 2010 with TFS 2010 gets you the source control, unit testing, automated build, work item tracking (bugs, user stories, etc...) for any VS verion from Pro upwards.

If you can affort to push the boat out (add about £900 per developer) for the Premium edition you get code coverage, coded UI tests, code metrics, code contracts and a number of other handy tools.

If you have a big budget (add about £2500 per dev) then the Ultimate version brings a huge swath of testing and test lab managment tools as well.